# Detecting mentions in UITextField not working

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I'm trying to detect mentions (using `@`) in a `UITextField`. Basically, what's I'm trying to do is convert the text `String` that's being entered by the user into an `array` and then loop through each item to see if there's a `@` prefix. For some reason, despite that I enter longer text around the mention (or the mention only), it shows 1 items that's an empty string. I'm doing something wrong apparently but I can't figure out what is it

```
if let mentionsArray = self.commentTextField.text?.components(separatedBy:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines) {

       for  mention in mentionsArray  {
           if mention.hasPrefix("@")  {
                print(mention)
           }
       }
 }
```

Worth mentioning that this code is ran inside of a closure.

**UPDATE:** The code was actually working, but the comment below asked about what's the content of `commentTextField.text` and it made me realize that I empty the content of the text field before I reach that point.

Comment: I just tested your code and it worked fine for me. Mind sharing more of your code?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri I've added the entire `IBAction`. PS: All of the `API` requests are to save data on the server  (which is `FirebaseDatabase`). The code is working, it does what it's supposed to do, except for that `mention` part.

Comment: What does mentionsArray contain? Check with breakpoint.

Comment: Tried that, it says it contains just 1 item, which is not true because I enter a lot longer content. Oh and that item is actually an empty string, which again, not correct and I don't know why it's not working

Comment: Okay then what does `commentTextField.text` contain?

Comment: Oh, man, I found it. I empty the text in the `UITextField` before it reaches that point. Smh. Thank you though. That comment above help me realize that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `commentTextField` is probably **empty**. Check if you are clearing the text field anywhere. If it is empty, `components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)` will return an empty string "".

Comment: Yup, that's exactly it! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You below extension which i used to detect the mentation text from string.

```
extension String {
        func findMentionText() -> [String] {
            var arr_hasStrings:[String] = []
            let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(@[a-zA-Z0-9_\\p{Arabic}\\p{N}]*)", options: [])
            if let matches = regex?.matches(in: self, options:[], range:NSMakeRange(0, self.count)) {
                for match in matches {
                    arr_hasStrings.append(NSString(string: self).substring(with: NSRange(location:match.range.location, length: match.range.length )))
                }
            }
            return arr_hasStrings
        }
    }
```